# Unity3D - Disabled GameObject scripts losing state

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a script component on a GameObject (simplified here) which is disabled upon creation, using `testObject.setActive(false)`.

```
using UnityEngine;

public TestObject : MonoBehaviour {
    public int testValue = 5;

    void Start() {
        testValue = 0;
    }

    public int GetTestValue() {
        return testValue;
    }
}
```

Before disabling, the return of GetTestValue is 0. Once I re-enable the object, the return is 5.

The Unity docs say:

> Making a GameObject inactive will disable every component ... Any scripts that you have attached to the GameObject will no longer have Update() called ...

However the behaviour of the Component suggests to me that the MonoBehaviour made by the script is not really 'disabled', but rather is destroyed. If it were only `Update()` that stopped being called, how does that explain the loss of state?

The underlying question here is: what is the intended way to temporarily disable a script without destroying it?

Comment: There must be more to it than what you say. If you set to false, all the Unity methods are not called by engine (Update, LateUpdate, Collision,...) but the public method can still be called from elsewhere and affect the state of the script. For instance, you can still call GetTestValue from another script even though it is inactive. Setting on and off will not affect the content of the variables nor will it destroy the instance. So either you are actually destroying and creating a new object elsewhere, or you are looking at 2 different objects or you are resetting the value somewhere else.

Comment: @Everts: You were right that there was 'more'. I should have stated explicitly that the deactivation occurred immediately after Instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, it turns out, was a race condition. TestObject was being deactivated before Start() could complete, and this prevented the object from being initialized properly. By moving the initialization code to Awake(), the object correctly set its state before deactivating.

Answer (score 4):

Well what actually happens is that the `Start()` function is **only called once in the lifetime of an object**. So at the beginning its called and sets the value to 0. But when you disable it and reactivate it, it isn't called.

This doesn't change the fact that even after deactivating and reactivating the script your value should still be the same (as we figured out in the comments section).

One way you could make this work is by using `OnEnable()` which will be called each time the Script is setActive. [More info on OnEnable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html):

> This function is called when the object becomes enabled and active.

So in your script you would have :

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    testValue = 0;
}
```

If you know this object will be Activated and deactivated many times and that you absolutely need to do something each time this happens.

---

Which brings me to my second point and my advice:

**Dont keep important values on scripts that will get deactivated and reactivated.**

Keep important information on a script that will never be deactivated so in that way you're always sure the value is always the correct one. So that way you don't always need to regenerate that correct value and check each time if it's actually the good value you got.

Comment: **only called once in the lifetime of an object** - It's clear that the object must not be destroyed in the deactivation because, as you say, Start() is only called once. This does not explain why the object loses its internal state.

Comment: @frog Its not losing its value you're simply overwriting it with that line `public int testValue = 5;`

Comment: That cannot be the case. The assignment of 5 to testValue is done in the object constructor--that is what the compiler automatically generates from initializer syntax. The constructor, like Start(), is only called once in the lifetime of an object. Thus testValue cannot _ever_ be overwritten by the field initializer.

Comment: @frog So I've been trying to recreate your problem but when I disable my object and reactivate it testValue is still 0, are you sure there's nothing else that's resetting your value?

Comment: Thank you for your input, @CNuts -- I failed to mention in the original question that I was calling `setActive(false)` on the line immediately after `Instantiate()`. See my answer below.

Comment: @frog I removed the part about overwriting because as you pointed out it wasn't true. I think the first time I tried it I deactivated it quickly also so it made me jump to this conclusion haha

Answer (score 0):

I have the opposite situation..I tried to set an animator parameter in Awake() and deactivate immediately. the parameter value did not changed. But if i put it in Start(), the value is set.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.